# TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 in windows server 2012 r2

Tags: tls1.2, windows-server-2012-r2

My question is simple. My server's operating system is Windows Server 2012 r2 and all updates were made on it.

When I run the [iiscrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) I couldn't find `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` cipher suite. To find this, should I use Windows server 2016 or is there another way to get it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Microsoft has a docs page that lists all the [Windows versions and their cipher suites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374757(v=vs.85).aspx).

First server version to support this cipher suite is indeed Windows Server 2016.

Comment: I simply cannot believe Microsoft would not add these to earlier versions of windows server.  In particular server 2012 R2.   How is an app deployed to these servers expected to talk to modern apis/services??

Comment: Install them on a Windows 2016 server.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Windows 2012 Server doesn't support tls-ecdhe-rsa-with-aes-256-gcm-sha384 or 256/128 Ciphers.